# How to copy cygwin mintty window settings to another computer?

Tags: cygwin, mintty

I'm wondering where does mintty keep its settings (like cursors, window size, font, etc. Basically what you get when right clicking on cygwin window header and selecting "Options..."). I need it to be able to automatically copy all the cygwin window settings to another PC, so basically any other way to do so will do.
Non of the paths mentioned in https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Tips exist on my machine (or I've missed something obvious).
Thanks.

Comment: look on `.minttyrc` on your home directory

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I must've somehow missed it.